# Determine if a formula is valid using equivalences

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Determine if a formula is valid using equivalences

Examples:

```
Valid. Proof:
A → (B → A) ≡ ¬A ∨ (¬B ∨ A) ≡ ¬A ∨ A ∨ ¬B ≡ true ∨ ¬B ≡ true

A ∨ (A ∨ B). Answer: Not valid. 
Model: A 7→ false, B 7→ false.
```

Here are my attempts at a couple of problems:

```
(1) (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B)
(A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B): Answer Invalid
Model: A→False, B→True

(2) (¬(A ∨ B)) → ¬B:
```

This one is incomplete

```
(¬(A ∨ B)) → ¬B ≡ ((A ∧ B)) → B ≡
```

I'm not really sure how to do proofs by equivalence.  I know deMorgan's laws are used here, but I'm struggling to understand how to apply it to actual problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

\begin{align}(A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B)&\equiv A\land(B\lor \lnot B)\tag{1) Distributive Law} \\ \\
&\equiv A \land \text{true}\tag{2, LEM}\\ \\
&\equiv A\end{align}

(1) So If $A$ is false, (and $B$ is either true or false), the expression evaluates to false.  On the other hand, if $A$ is true, the statement is true.  So the truth value of the statement is "contingent".

*NOTE: "LEM" is short for the Law of the Excluded Middle.
$$ $$
\begin{align}(\lnot(A \lor B)) \to \lnot B &\equiv \lnot\lnot (A\lor B) \lor \lnot B \tag{2}\\ \\
&\equiv (A\lor B)\lor \lnot B\\ \\
&\equiv A \lor (B \lor \lnot B)\\ \\
&\equiv A \lor \text{true} \\ \\ 
&\equiv \text{true}\end{align}

Note that this statement (2), is a tautology, true no matter what the truth values assigned to $A, B$.  I'll let you

Comment: Thank you! This helps a bunch!

Comment: So, can you see that $(1)$ is not valid in any truth value assignment when $A$ is false?  (2)  This is a tautology, meaning is true under all possible truth-value assignments to A, B.

Comment: Why the downvote?